# I can't use any of my antivirus, and none of it will load (or the websites) will load. help please

Tags: windows-10, virus, malware, anti-virus

i cant go to an antivirus website, nor can i open malwarebytes because it says "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000017). Click OK to close the application." im aware that this is some type of malware. im panicking right now, but ive tried to go into safe mode but it still blocks it for me even there. what can i do to delete the virus?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . I understand that it's stressful for you and difficult to get all the info together, but the way it's written it's impossible to help you. Please edit the question and add much more details on each thing ("an antivirus website", which one? Tried another one? "but it still blocks it for me even there", blocks you from going to the website, opening Malwarebytes, or both? (And also, what do you know to have been done on the PC before this started?)

Comment: That is largely what I answered and it was deleted. I waste my time in here trying to help.

Comment: @John - The only reason, the answer you submitted was deleted, is because you deleted it after a single downvote.

Comment: Like I said. I am wasting my time in here trying to help. My work is worthless in here.

Comment: @John - tbh, the true waste of time was in dropping a short & not entirely convincing* answer to a very well-established dupe, knowing it would be closed in minutes. *Too late to backup now; backups should have been done before infection.

Comment: I have asked support to delete my answers because I am wasting my time here .

Comment: @John -  Which 'support'? You can't delete answers once past a certain point. You gave up that right by posting them under [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) You can have posts dissociated, but not deleted. You need to ask staff for that & you need  good reason, not 'rage quit'.

Comment: I went  SU Support and contacted them to remove my posts.

Comment: @John - They won't be deleted.  You might have those answers disassociated with your user profile at most, since you have hundreds of answers with dozens of **upvotes. Keep in mind you have thousands of answers, nobody is going to delete, thousands of helpful answers to questions

Comment: Whatever. I will see if they answer me (they often do not).